# Different ways to initialize camera view matrix

Tags: c#, matrix, xna, camera

What are some of the ways you can create the view matrix for a camera in XNA?

So far I've only seen the `createLookAt()` method and was curious as to what else was possible.

It appears on the [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197914) that `creatLookAt()` is the only matrix method for constructing a view matrix.

**EDIT:**

Here's a good [tutorial](http://stevehazen.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/matrix-basics-how-to-step-away-from-storing-an-orientation-as-3-angles/) on how the world matrix is composed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view matrix is nothing more than a typical matrix (representing a world space orientation and position) that happens to be inverted.

If you know how to create a typical world space matrix, simply invert it and it becomes a view matrix.

For instance, in Xna:

```
Matrix m = Matrix.CreateYawPitchRoll(yawFloat, pitchFloat, rollFloat) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(someVector3);

Matrix myViewMatrix = Matrix.Invert(m);
```

myViewMatrix will work as expected in your effects.

Comment: I didn't know it was an inverted view matrix. Thanks! Also, I read your [post](http://stevehazen.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/matrix-basics-how-to-step-away-from-storing-an-orientation-as-3-angles/) and it was very helpful in understanding how the information is stored within a Matrix.